# how to send a value from one class to another using pyqt4 and python

Tags: python, pyqt4, qthread

i'm having some trouble in building my app, I have a GUI made in pyqt4 and Python, I use QThread to check the cpu load every 2 seconds and I want to diplay it on a progress bar. My GUI is in one class and my Qthread is in the other.

This is my code: pyqt classes, my code printscreen

[image]

I want to know how to pass my values collected in QThread to Qobjects in my other Class.

```
import sys,os,module,config_read,time,threading,datecs_print,mysql.connector as mariadb,commandList
import psutil,logging
from PyQt4 import QtGui, uic ,QtSql,QtCore
from PyQt4.QtCore import QThread, SIGNAL
import resources
import webbrowser
sys.stderr = open("errlog.txt", "w")

class systemValues(QThread):
    def __init__(self):
        QThread.__init__(self)

    def __del__(self):
        self.wait()

    def cpuRunValue(self):
        while (1):
            for x in range(2):
                p = psutil.cpu_percent(1,False)
                return p

    def cpuProgressBarUpdate(self):
        while(1):
            # MyWindow.setcpuBarValue(val=77)
            MyWindow.cpuBar.setValue(value=77)

    def run(self):
        # self.cpuRunValue()
        print(self.cpuRunValue())
       # self.cpuProgressBarUpdate()

class MyWindow(QtGui.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        QtGui.QDialog.__init__(self)
        super(MyWindow, self).__init__()
        file_path = os.path.abspath("ui/sales_window.ui")
        uic.loadUi(file_path, self)
        self.myThread = systemValues()
        self.myThread.start()

    def setcpuBarValue(self):
        threading.Thread(target=self.cpuBar.setValue(systemValues.cpuRunValue())).start()
```

This is my code, I get no error. I just cant transfer my value I get from cpuRunValue() to QprogressBar from MyWindow. I'm not very experienced with this.

PS: I eliminated lots of code that's not necessary, but please let me know if you need more info.
Thank You.

Comment: Please include the code as text in your example. Also please tell use what the error message is you get.

Comment: @titusjan i have added my code, is it ok for you? any thoughts? thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to use threads in Qt then you must understand them well. For instance read [this page](https://wiki.qt.io/Threads_Events_QObjects) first. Certainly don't mix the `QThread` with the `threading` package from the Python standard library.

I hope you're not offended if I think that your probably fairly new to programming. I advise you to not use threads (in general and in Qt) until you have more experience. Threads are hard to use correctly, even for seasoned programmers, and therefore should only be used if necessary. For this reason the Qt documentation on threads even includes a [section about alternatives](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/thread-basics.html#when-to-use-alternatives-to-threads).

You want to execute a function every 2 seconds, so in your case the best solution is to use a `QTimer` and connect its `timeout` signal to a slot that updates the progress bar. Like so:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import sys
import psutil
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtWidgets

class MyWidget(QtWidgets.QWidget):

    def __init__(self, parent=None):

        super().__init__(parent=parent)

        self.layout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout()
        self.setLayout(self.layout)

        self.progressBar = QtWidgets.QProgressBar()
        self.layout.addWidget(self.progressBar)

        self.timer = QtCore.QTimer()
        self.timer.timeout.connect(self.updateCpu)
        self.timer.start(100) # Every 0.1 seconds

    def updateCpu(self):
        cpu = psutil.cpu_percent(None, False)
        #print("cpu = {}%".format(cpu))
        self.progressBar.setValue(cpu)


def main():
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)

    win = MyWidget()
    win.show()
    win.raise_()
    app.exec_()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Note that I changed the first parameter of `cpu_percent` to `None`. This makes the call return immediately instead of lasting one second (and therefore you can update the progress bar more often if you want). Setting it to `None` causes the first call of `cpu_percent` to return a meaningless value, but in your cause that's not an issue I think. See [the documention](https://pythonhosted.org/psutil/#psutil.cpu_percent).

Finally, even though you removed a lot of unnecessary code, your code example was not yet **minimal** (e.g. the `import datecs_print` is not necessary to run it, and I don't have this module). I was also not **complete** (e.g. the "ui/sales_window.ui" file was missing so I couldn't run it). Please read the page on [how to make an MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). You will get a lot more help next time if you include a small program that we can just copy-paste-execute.

Hope this helps

Comment: hi, thank you for your answer, i'm new to python, i started to learn python 4 month ago, my previous programming language was Pascal in highschool, i learned python by myself. i'm aware the code is not very "professional". i'll try to implement your ideea. i was using thread and qthread because someone suggested to me.

Comment: i've tested the app with your idee Qtimer, it's not working properly, the app is freezing for a few msec or sec and is not very responsive, i've read your link about QThread and it looks like i need to use QThread for paralel running. So my problem is i dont understand very well how to pass a signal from one class to another, because this is the good way for passing values from one Qt class to another. If you can help me with an example i appreciate your effort. i'm not a native english speaker and not very experienced with this.  thank you

Comment: Be sure to set the first parameter of `psutil.cpu_percent` to `None`. What happens if you run my example without modifications? Is this unresponsive as well?

Comment: hi again I've checked the code again, and with your value set to `None` the app seems to work well, I might have forgot about this and copied from my original program. thanks a lot. i'll vote this as my answer. take care